# MongoDB + Node.js : How to use a Schema from an external file for another Schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, types, schema

I have a classes (or models) that needs to use another class as part of its properties as shown below.

** Header for both files **

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema =       mongoose.Schema;
```

**item.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
    var ItemSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        cost: Number
    });
    mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
}
```

**receipt.js**

```
ItemModel = require('./item.js');

var Item = mongoose.model('Item');

module.exports = function() {

    var LineItemSchema = new Schema({
        item:   Item,
        amount: Number
    });

    var LineItem = mongoose.model('LineItem', LineItemSchema);

    var ReceiptSchema = new Schema({
        name:   String,
        items:  [LineItemSchema]
    });
    mongoose.model('Receipt', ReceiptSchema);
}
```

In the LineItem class, I'm trying to set the type of the variable 'item' to the class type, Item, node.js or mongoose.js is screaming at me about it saying that there's a type error.

How can I use a Schema "type" from an external file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you are wrapping all of this in an anonymous function. But to reference a schema from another schema, you can do the following:

```
var LineItemSchema = new Schema({
    item: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Item'
    },
    amount: Number
});
```

And of course you need to require the Schema object:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Comment: I'm not sure either, I saw it in some tutorial that didn't explain why. I'm new to this express.js and mongoose.js thing. I can see this as a good solution, but I don't quite understand why. Is ref a mongoosejs reserved keyword. I think type might be as well. Or is ref just a variable the programmer makes up? Is this the only way to differentiate Object types?

Comment: @user3228667: Yes, `type` and `ref` are "reserved" keywords. You use `ref` not to differentiate object types, but to reference other models.

Answer (score 0):

In `item.js` have it return the schema from a self-executing function.

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var ItemSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        cost: Number
    });
    mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
    return ItemSchema;
})();
```

Then in `receipt.js` you now can use the schema just like you used LineItemSchema.

```
var ItemSchema = require('./item.js');

// This should still create the model just fine.
var Item = mongoose.model('Item');

module.exports = function() {

var LineItemSchema = new Schema({
    item:   [ItemSchema], // This line now can use the exported schema.
    amount: Number
});

var LineItem = mongoose.model('LineItem', LineItemSchema);

var ReceiptSchema = new Schema({
    name:   String,
    items:  [LineItemSchema]
});
mongoose.model('Receipt', ReceiptSchema);

}
```

This is all speculation and untested.

Comment: I'm not sure either, I saw it in some tutorial that didn't explain why. I'm new to this express.js and mongoose.js thing. 

I see that you put square brackets around the ItemSchema. I tried that out in my code by also putting square brackets around my Item Schema, [Item], and it worked. However, wouldn't that just make it an array when it shouldn't be? I just want it to be one item.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, the square brackets would make it an array of those schema items.  `item: ItemSchema` should work then.  I gave my answer assuming you'd like to reuse the ItemSchema for more than one other schema, is that correct?  Breaking up the schemas in multiple js files makes sense if you need to reuse them.

Comment: I realized that I was wrong about what I said when I said, "I know that Item is a model and not a schema". It's a schema, and works the same as your way. But it doesn't work. I get a type error. The only way to fix this is to use Schema.ObjectId, which is broad because it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue then found that I can fix it by just exporting Schema from Item.js

Example:

```
Item.js
-----------

    const ItemSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        cost: Number
    });
    module.exports = ItemSchema;
```

and can use this schema in other models like this

```
    const ItemSchema = require('./item.js');

    const LineItemSchema = new Schema({
        item: {
            type: ItemSchema,
        }
    });
```